# Can't get work EclipseLink DynamicEntity with Oracle sequence

Tags: oracle, jpa, orm, eclipselink, sequence

I'm trying to persist Dynamic Entity with EclipseLink 2.3. If I'm not configuring sequence and just assign a value to field it works. Also not setting a value works, sequence is working with trigger in database. But I want to get generated id of field(next value of sequence).

There is a simple table with 2 columns RD_ID and RD_NAME and I'm assuming I should use NativeSequence for Oracle Sequence.

```
...
Sequence seq = new NativeSequence("RD_SEQ", 1);
dynamicTypeBuilder.configureSequencing(seq, "RD_SEQ", "RD_ID");
...
DynamicEntity entity;
entity = (DynamicEntity) classDesc.getInstantiationPolicy().buildNewInstance();
// entity.set("rdId", new BigDecimal(1));
entity.set("rdName", "some text");

...
getEntityManager().persist(entity);
System.out.println(entity.get("rdId"));
```

thrown Exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Error Code: 942
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:2831)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.update(QuerySequence.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.updateAndSelectSequence(QuerySequence.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.StandardSequence.getGeneratedVector(StandardSequence.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.DefaultSequence.getGeneratedVector(DefaultSequence.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.Sequence.getGeneratedVector(Sequence.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager$Preallocation_Transaction_NoAccessor_State.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.ClientSessionSequencing.getNextValue(ClientSessionSequencing.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.assignSequenceNumber(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4231)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4176)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:440)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:269)
...
```

Am I missing something or should I use different approach to get sequence number?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error, you are using TABLE sequencing, and you have no SEQUENCE table.  You need to create this table if you wish to use TABLE sequencing.

You seem to want to use an Oracle SEQUENCE, so you need to register the NativeSequence object with the Session's login.

session.getLogin().addSequence(sequence);

You should ensure you register the sequence before connecting the Session.

Comment: Thanks @James, registering sequence to the session is worked.